# How to disable text chat in Gmod?

Tags: garrys-mod

My younger brother (10) likes to play Garry's Mod, but when he plays online, he sees lots of bad words in the text chat. Is there a way he can play online, but with the text chat disabled? Or if that's not possible, can I set it up so that the profanity is filtered out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hud_saytext_time 0` should do what you want. It's a client ConVar that controls the amount of time chat messages are visible for before decaying -- obviously setting it to `0` will cause them to not show up at all.

Do note that you can still see messages if you actually open up the chat: if that's an issue, you can simply unbind whatever keys you use for chat (`y` by default).

Answer (score -3):

Open up Garry's mod and press <kbd>~</kbd> and then type `hud_saytext_time 0`.

You will have to do that each time you open up the game.

Comment: This question was already answered, and you're not adding anything to it